# access credentials error in Copy Command in S3

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2

I am facing access credentials error when i ran copy Command in S3.

my copy command is :

```
copy part from 's3://lntanbusamplebucket/load/part-csv.tbl'
credentials 'aws_access_key_id=D93vB$;yYq'
csv;
```

error message is:

```
  error:  Invalid credentials. Must be of the format: credentials 'aws_iam_role=...' or 'aws_access_key_id=...;aws_secret_access_key=...[;token=...]'
```

'aws_access_key_id=?;
aws_secret_access_key=?''

Could you please can any one explain what is aws_access_key_id and aws_secret_access_key ?

where we can see this?

Thanks in advance.
Mani

Answer (score 2):

The access key you're using looks more like a secret key, they usually look something like "AKIAXXXXXXXXXXX".

Also, don't post them openly in StackOverflow questions. If someone gets a hold of a set of access keys, they can access your AWS environment.

Access Key & Secret Key are the most basic form of credentials / authentication used in AWS. One is useless without the other, so if you've lost one of the two, you'll need to regenerate a set of keys.

To do this, go into the AWS console, go to the IAM services (Identity and Access Management) and go into users. Here, select the user that you're currently using (probably yourself) and go to the Security Credentials tab.

Here, under Access keys, you can see which sets of keys are currently active for this user. You can only have 2 sets active at one time, so if there's already 2 sets present, delete one and create a new pair. You can download the new pair as a file called "credentials.csv" and this will contain your user, access key and secret key.

Comment: No problem, if it helped you please mark the answer as accepted so that other people can see this helped you.